# Active admin don't remove record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In activeadmin: when I click remove record and redirect to show page, the record is not removed. Why? I don't understand. 5 hours ago it was working successful, but now..not working.

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations" }
  get 'persons/profile'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  get 'persons/profile', as: 'user_root'
  get 'products/search', as: 'products_search'

  resources :products, only: [:index,:show]

  resource :order, path: :basket, only: [:show, :update, :destroy], as: :basket do
    get :form_order,  as: :details
    resources :order_items, only: [:create]
  end

  resources :order_items, only: [:destroy] do
    post :increment
    post :decrement
    post :set_count
  end
end
```